# My image won't show up using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

coords=1017,474
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1080, height=960)
frame = Frame(root,width=1080, height=960)

def cords(event):
    print(event.x,event.y)



def click(event):
    canvas.create_line(event.x,event.y,coords)

canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>',click)
canvas.bind('<Button-1>',cords)


photo=PhotoImage('images.png')
label=Label(frame,image=photo)
label.grid(column=60)

frame.pack(side='right')
canvas.pack(side='left')
root.mainloop()
```

my issue is this when I run this code the image I have won't show up at all however everything else works. if someone could help me find out whats wrong that would be helpful. There are no other issues I can find.

Comment: no the previous time my window did not have the right size now every thing works but the image doesn't appear

Comment: many versions of tkinter do not support .png. Try with a .gif and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: no it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must supply the file as the value of the `file` keyword argument. By not specifying `file=`, the first argument is being used as the internal name of the image.

```
photo=PhotoImage(file='images.png')
```

Slightly more information is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28010236/7432

Answer (score 0):

I would try these:

```
photo=PhotoImage(file = 'images.png')
label.config(image = photo)
```

Comment: When answering it's important to format code in code blocks, which can be done by marking the text and press the {} symbol or add 4 spaces before each line. Also, a short explanation would be very beneficial.